# Umbraco 7 - How do I get the published date from IPublishedContent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system, umbraco

I am having trouble finding the published date. I working the Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent interface, which doesn't seem to have a published date, only a created and updated date.

All the docs I found on the interwebs, suggest using Document(id), then Document.ReleasedDate, but this now marked obsolete. It suggests to use the ReleaseDate in Umbraco.Core.Models.Content class.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the UpdateDate on IPublishedContent. That date is always updated when you publish content.

The ReleaseDate that you mention is used to set a future date and time for when a specific content item should be published (automatically). So that is not the date you are after. When a release date is set the UpdateDate will also be updated with this date once the item is published.

Comment: If I use the UpdateDate, and publish an article, and then go back three days later to fix up a spelling mistake, now "published date" is off by three day. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If that is your scenario it would be better to add a 'Publish Date' property to your content. You can then choose to set the date through an event handler, which ensures that the date is only updated upon first publish or simply have it as a required field which the content editor can choose whichever date they want.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll have to go with adding a 'Publish Date' property and  create an event handler.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction in how set up this event handler and to hook into when the publish an article? I'm brand new to Umbraco.

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco content items don't have a built-in property to indicate when they were first published.

If you want a reliable indication of when content was actually published, the best option is to add a custom property to your document type. You can then add an event handler to your application, which updates the property to the current date when it is first published:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the publishedDate property when content is first published
    /// </summary>
    public class UpdatePublishDateEventHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        protected override void ApplicationInitialized(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            ContentService.Published += ContentService_Published;
        }

        void ContentService_Published(Umbraco.Core.Publishing.IPublishingStrategy sender, Umbraco.Core.Events.PublishEventArgs<Umbraco.Core.Models.IContent> e)
        {
            const string publishedDateKey = "publishedDate";
            var contentService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
            foreach (var content in e.PublishedEntities.Where(x => x.HasProperty(publishedDateKey)))
            {
                var existingValue = content.GetValue(publishedDateKey);
                if (existingValue == null)
                {
                    content.SetValue(publishedDateKey, DateTime.Now);
                    contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(content, raiseEvents: false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Umbraco automatically scans for and activates classes that inherit from ApplicationEventHandler at start-up, so you simply need to add the above class to your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Umbraco 7 take a look at the **ReleaseDate** property on the Umbraco.Core.Models.IContent interface. Apparently it "Gets or sets the date the Content should be released and thus be published".

Comment: It's already reported in the reply above you. That's not what pwee is looking for since that date gets reset after every change.

Comment: I've done my own tests and I've found that 'ReleaseDate', which is labeled in the back office as "Publish at" does not change after making a modification (such as a spelling correction). So I was able to use this for my need. Thanks @Teppic.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should probably be using the".Created" date. As this will be the date the article was originally published.

Alternatively you could use a custom DateTime property on your DocType and use that as the publish date by retrieving it as follows:

```
YourNodeObject.GetPropertyValue<DateTime>("customPropertyAliasHere");
```

Regards